# When an NSWindow object has a delegate that is a NSWindow subclass, who is responsible to act on received events?

Tags: cocoa

So I'm building a program that features the use of the IKImageBrowserView component as a subview in an NSWindow. As a side note, I have a controller object called **ImageBrowserController** which subclasses NSWindow and is set as the delegate of the NSWindow object of my app.

I have sent IKImageBrowserView the message setCanControlQuickLookPanel:YES to enable it to automatically use the QuickLook functionality to preview image files when the IKImageBrowserView is a first responder to receive key events. Then it took me a while to figure out how to make the IKImageBrowserView a first responder which I finally got working by overriding acceptsFirstResponder inside my **ImageBrowserController**.

Now I understand that as the delegate to the NSWindow, **ImageBrowserController** has a place in the responder chain after the event gets triggered on NSWindow. And I understand that as a subview of NSWindow, IKImageBrowserView is in line to be passed events for event handling. What I don't get is where the connection is between the **ImageBrowserController** being a first responder and the event somehow making it to the IKImageBrowserView. I didn't set NSWindow or IKImageBrowserView as first responders explicitly. So why isn't it necessary for me to implement event handling inside my **ImageBrowserController**?

**EDIT:** So after reading the accepted answer and going back to my code I tried removing the acceptsFirstResponder override in my **ImageBrowserController** and the QuickLook functionality still triggered just like the accepted answer said it would. Commenting out the setCanControlQuickLookPanel:YES made the app beep at me when I tried to invoke QuickLook functionality via the spacebar. I'm getting the feeling that my troubles were caused by user error of XCode in hitting the RUN button instead of the BUILD button after making changes to my code (*sigh*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of what you are saying regarding the interactions between your objects does not make sense, and it is hard to address your stated question without some background.

As you say, your window delegate has a place at the *end* of the responder chain, after the window itself. The key point I think you are missing is that GUI elements, such as your `IKImageBrowserView`, will be at the *beginning* of the chain, and any one of them in a given window could be the current `firstResponder`.

When your application gets an event, it passes it off to the key window (which is just the window which currently accepts "key" (i.e., "keystroke") events). That window begins by asking its `firstResponder` to handle the event. If that object refuses, it passes the event to its own `nextResponder`, usually its superview, which either handles it or passes it on, until the event has either been handled or passed all the way up to the window object itself. Only then will the window (if it does not handle the event itself) ask its delegate to handle the event.

This means that the connection between the window delegate and the `IKImageBrowserView` is only through the [Responder Chain](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH3-SW2), and its nature is simply that if the view declines to handle any given event, the delegate may eventually be asked to handle it, *if no other object in between them handles it first*.

Your window delegate does not need to be a `firstResponder`. Nor does overriding `acceptsFirstResponder` on the window delegate have any effect on one of the window's subviews.*

Your window delegate also does not need to (and, indeed *should not*) be a subclass of `NSWindow`. All it needs is to be a subclass of `NSObject` which implements whatever methods from the [`NSWindowDelegate Protocol`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) you are interested in, and methods to handle any events you might want to catch if they are not handled by other objects.

So, the answer to your explicit question at the end is (and I do not mean this sarcastically): you only need to implement event handling in your window delegate if you want it to handle events itself.

---

*: `IKImageBrowserView` already responds `YES` to `acceptsFirstResponder`. If there are no other subviews in your window, it will automatically be the `firstResponder` when your application starts. You can set this `initialFirstResponder` explicitly in Interface Builder by connecting that outlet on the window to whatever object you want.

Comment: @josh-caswell - Thanks for the answer. Your comment helped me figure out what I was misunderstanding.

Comment: Great! I wasn't completely sure whether I was telling you things you already knew. Glad it was useful.